# UI Aesthetic vs. Accepted/Expected Functionality

Tags: actionscript-3, user-interface, user-experience

The issue I've come up against is the designer seems to have taken an aesthetic approach to the gui design in favor of expected functionality.  In this case, I have a new layout for a video player that I'm implementing - the graphics are great - but it is missing the Video Playhead Time and Duration.  There is a seek bar and there is also a time overlay when you seek, but it just shows the user where they are seeking to.  No where is there any available interface or display showing the current time.  There is also metadata (notes) that have specific times associated with them, but nothing specific for the player.

Any thoughts on what would be the best way to argue that this is not the best approach and that like all the other video player interfaces we have, we need to put the time code on the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could argue that it is impossible for someone to share a specific part of the video. If it's particularly long and you only want to tell someone about the scene that happens at 5:43, it will be impossible. You can't just say *"move the slider about 2 and a half quarters in"*. It would be confusing and unnecessary.

Also point out that the majority of the time, things like these are merely novelty and not practical. Novelty wares of very quickly, especially when the novelty provides an inconvenience to the user when they will already be used to video players from YouTube and Vimeo, both featuring the bare minimum components required for a video player to be effective. Yet at the same time they both allow for distinctive visual styles.

Anyway that's how I feel about it all, hope this helps.

Comment: I really like the idea of it being 'Novelty' - that puts it in a way that might be less harsh than just coming out and saying it's the wrong approach.